# Adding Images Dynamically into Swiper JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I have a page where images need to showed in slider.

```js
// Initializing the Swiper
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    freeMode: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 1000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    watchSlidesProgress: true,

});

var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 1000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper,
    },
});

$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // top
        swiper.slidePrev();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // bottom
        swiper.slideNext();
    }
});


let image_list = ["https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg", "https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg",
"https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg",
"https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg",
"https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg"]
// Adding Images
for (i = 0; i < image_list.length; i++) {
    let div = '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="' + image_list[i] + '" alt=""/></div>';
    $("#large-img").append(div);
    $("#small-img").append(div);
}
```

```css
/* SWIPER JS */
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.mySwiper2 {
    height: 27rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper {
    height: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />


<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0;">
    <div class="row g-0 justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="large-img">
                    <!-- Images coming from the backend through javascript -->
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

            </div>

            <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="small-img">
                    <!-- Images coming from the backend through javascript -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

When I am adding the Images Dynamically through the javascript into the HTML template, the `SWIPER` doesnt work. I am actually passing the `media` url of the image in the `img.src` attribute as I am using Django as the backend. No matter from where you pass the image url, it doesnt work.

`**UPDATE**` : In running this code, it works on the full screen mode (Only the autoplay and next and previous button. Clicking on the thumbnail isnt working) and in the small window which opens when pressing the `Run Snippet`, the Swiper.js doesnt work. The problem in the small window is similar to what I am seeing in my website.

Comment: if you add them manually in the html does it work? :)

Comment: Yes, Manual adding is working

Comment: What if you add a setTimout around the Swipper creation, just to check if you load it a bit later it works? Maybe is something related about the time to load images and the library load...  I would try this in debugging.

Comment: So you are suggesting that swiper should load after the images have been loaded on the DOM?

Comment: I don't know this library, but I would try to see if that helps.

Comment: Yo bro. It totally worked. I have tried this type of technique but I was trying to load the `Swiper` just above loading the images. I dont know why I was thinking to initialize the `Swiper` before loading the images rather than loading it after

Comment: Glad it works, I've answered below, you can accept it if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `Swiper` after loading the images, this way it can use the images when initializing. Maybe it would be a good way to check the Swipper documentation, I saw it has some lazy loading parameters which could possibly help solve this differently.

doc:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading